# In Generic class overriding why some class retun null value? please execute following code

Tags: java

progam for Generic Overriding:
class code: contains genric super and generic subclass having show() as overridden ans trying to find out based on what condition the overridden method will execute.

```
class GA<T>{
    private T type;
    public GA(){

    }
    public GA(T type) {
         this.type = type;
    }
    public <T> void show(){
        System.out.println("GA:"+this.type);
    }
}
class GB<T> extends GA<T>{
    private T type;
    public GB(T type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public <T> void show(T type){
        System.out.println("GB:"+type);
    }
}

public class VarArg {
    public static <T> void show(T... a) {
        System.out.println("Element Length:" + a.length);
        for (T aa : a) {
             System.out.println("Element:" + aa);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        show(5, 5, 5, 5);
        show(5.2, 5.1, 5.5);
        GA[] arrayStr = {new GA<String>("Str"),new GB<Integer>(10),new GA<Double>(5.5)};
        for(GA ga: arrayStr ){
            ga.show();
        }
        GA<String> str = new GB<String>("H");
        str.show();
    }
}
```

Result contains GA: null. I am not able to understand why it is coming

Result:

```
Element Length:4
Element:5
Element:5
Element:5
Element:5
Element Length:3
Element:5.2
Element:5.1
Element:5.5
GA:Str
GA:null
GA:5.5
GA:null
```

Comment: You are not calling `super(type)` in `GB`'s constructor and the default constructor of `GA` leaves `type` uninitialized.  There are two `type` fields shadowing each other.  (Did you want that?)

Comment: You can simplify your example by removing the `show()` method from the `VarArg` class. This method has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your `private T type;` in class `GB` is actually a *different* field than `type` in `GA`, as it is not possible to override or re-declare fields of superclasses in subclasses. Now, in the constructor of `GB`, since there is no explicit `super(...)`, implicitly the default constructor of the superclass is invoked - which leaves `GA.this.type` at `null`.

Furthermore, your `show` method in class `GB` is not overridden, since it has a different parameter list than that in `GA`. And more than that, it's never getting called anywhere.